# Lightning for Outlook adding new trusted domain

Tags: lightning-outlook

I am configuring Lightning for Outlook with an on-premise Exchange first time. As part of this config I need to add a domain that pertain to my Exchange by clicking on the "New" button under the "Microsoft® Outlook® Web App Domain" table.

[image]

Does anyone know what values should go into Developer Name and Master Label fields? I've looked through all the documentation and can't find any information on these two fields and where to obtain the values from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer name must start with a letter, must be unique in your organization, and must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores. I suspect that this will be used to migrate settings between orgs using the Metadata API, although it doesn't seem possible today. The Master Label label is kind of deceptive, but it appears that it's just a label for you to keep track of which domain is which. In other words, use whatever values you feel like, but they should be meaningful to you for maintenance and migration purposes. The configuration page itself doesn't have a "Help for this page", nor does there appear to be any documentation. It's likely that they simply haven't documented it yet, so it'd probably be useful to log some feedback with the documentation team.